# How to find the limit of this multivariable function

Tags: calculus

$\frac {x^2+y^2}{(1+y^2)}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

I tried going from y = 0 and y = x and some other things but it still got me to 0. The same happened when I tried using polar coordinates

Comment: This is well-defined in $(0,0)$ and the value is $0$ and it is continouus. Are you sure $0$ isn't what you want? Are you sure the expression is stated correctly?

Comment: Yes,  you're right, the limit exists and it's 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can just plug in the values directly. To show that it also works with polar coordinates see here:

$$\lim_{x\to (0,0)}{x^2+y^2\over {1+y^2}} =\lim_{r \to 0}{r^2 \cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta \over {1+r^2 \sin^2\theta}} =\lim_{r \to 0}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta \over {{1\over r^2}+ \sin^2\theta}} = \lim_{r \to 0}{1 \over {{1\over r^2}+ \sin^2\theta}} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $1\le 1+y^2$, then $\frac{1}{1+y^2}\le1$. Thus $0\le\frac{x^2+y^2}{1+y^2}\le x^2+y^2\to 0$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

So, $\frac{x^2+y^2}{1+y^2}\to 0$ if $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Comment: You can just plug in $x=0$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on whether or not he knows about continuity